# C++ generic task interface for delayed execution

Tags: c++, design-patterns, queue, c++17, interface

I want to rework my current game-server engine to use some global queue of tasks which will be distributed through all the working threads.

I started with task interface. I want it to be able to accept any kind of method and store it under queue for later execution. I'd like to hear your opinions on my implementation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

class ITask
{
public:
    virtual ~ITask() = default;
    virtual void execute() = 0;
};

class GameTask : public ITask
{
public:
    GameTask(std::function<void()> func) : func_(func) {}

    void execute() final
    {
        func_();
    }

private:
    std::function<void()> func_;
};

// lets imitate some bigger classes with various methods
class BigClassA
{
public:
    void func1(int a) { std::cout << ++a; }
    int func2(const std::string& s) { std::cout << s; return b; }

    int b = 4;
};

class BigClassB
{
public:
    double func1(BigClassA& bca, int i) { bca.b += i; return 0.1; }
};

int main()
{
    BigClassA a;
    BigClassB b;

    // perform immidiately by current main thread:
    a.func1(2);
    b.func1(a, 3);
    a.func2("Hello");

    //store under queue for later execution
    std::queue<std::unique_ptr<ITask>> queue;

    queue.push(std::make_unique<GameTask>( [&a]() { a.func1(2); } ));

    queue.push(std::make_unique<GameTask>( [&a, &b]() {b.func1(a, 3); } ));

    queue.push(std::make_unique<GameTask>( [&a]() { a.func2("Hello"); } ));


    // delayed execution
    while (queue.size())
    {
        queue.front()->execute();
        queue.pop();
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Which part of the code do you want to review? The `BigClass*` part falls under the category of [hypothetical code](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1709), so you may want to extract the core part and list the "lets imitate some bigger classes with various methods" as an usage example to avoid getting your question closed. Also, please include a brief explanation of what the code does. Thanks.

Comment: @L.F. To me it doesn't look like it's devoid of all meaning that it's unanswerable. Maybe you could say what's missing?

Comment: @Peilonrayz I think the task part is fine, but the name of the classes (`BigClassA`) may accumulate some CVs.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your contribution all. Im new to this sub and Its my first review request. The intention of that topic was to review the correctness of my queue for many kind of tasks that will be more expanded but will all contain execute function.

Also back to the 'BigClassA' thing. Since im working on pretty complex and big project that contains many classes and methods I wanted to try to imitate many diversified things that my abstraction can met and it should be able to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does effectively nothing but add a useless layer of indirection.

There is functionally nothing different between a simple `std::queue<std::function<void()>> queue;` and your OOP for the sake of OOP hierarchy and queue of unique_ptrs to pure interface.

Comment: Thats right, Im going to modify and expand ITasks deriveds in the future. I wanted to hear your opinions about that skeleton of my task queue

Comment: @Piodo flesh it out and then come back, There is nothing here to comment on other than that it's abstraction for abstraction's sake.